# Captcha image is generated but numbers are not generated

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp, captcha

This is generate.php code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
header('content-type:image/jpeg');
$text=$_SESSION['secure'];
$font_size=30;
$width=100;
$height=40;
$image=imagecreate($width, $height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color=imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$font='Consolas.ttf';
for($x=1; $x <= 30; $x++) {
    $x1 = rand(1, 100);
    $y1 = rand(1, 100);
    $x2 = rand(1, 100);
    $y2 = rand(1, 100);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $text);
}
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, $font, $text);
$imgSrc="out.png";
imagepng($image, $imgSrc);
?>
```

This is HTML code to display an image, here out.png is successfully generated and loaded into the page but numbers cannot be found.

```
<div class="form-group mx-auto text-center">
    <input type="hidden" name="cap_hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['secure']; ?>">
    <img src="out.png">
</div>
```

I have found one similar question but it didnt help me, thats why I have posted it here. 
The problem is the image is generated with lines only but no numbers are visible.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is Text on the Image but it is white.
Perhaps you could change the Colors of the Text.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecolorallocate.php

> These parameters are integers between 0 and 255 or hexadecimals
>   between 0x00 and 0xFF.

`0` would be Black and `255` would be White.

You might want to look at the Example at
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

```
// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);
```

You also might have a look at your Script at:

```
$image=imagecreate($width, $height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color=imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
```

The Result of `imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);` isnt assigned anywhere.

Comment: I see the Result of `imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);` isnt assigned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the font didn't load correctly.

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path. [PHP: imagettftext - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)